# How to override Bootstrap's CSS forcing underlines on link text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, inheritance

I am using Bootstrap 5 and have a `<div>` that is wrapped in an `<a>`. It contains a title, a thumbnail image, and some description text. In other words, the entire block of content is a link.

I have been able to override most of Bootstrap's CSS, but when it comes to this link text it's really persistent.

If I specify `display: inline-block` the underlines disappear. But I want that for `inline` text here as well. `text-decoration: none` is not taking effect.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Underline</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="py-0">

<main>

    <div class="row mb-3 report-with-img-cont">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 report-previews themed-grid-col">
            
            <a href="/">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>
                            <span>This is a Title</span>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 themed-grid-col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 themed-grid-col"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the underline from all text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `text-decoration-none` class in your `<a>` tag, and that will remove your forcing underlines on link text. and refer the below link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-decoration

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Underline</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="py-0">
  <main>
    <div class="row mb-3 report-with-img-cont">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 report-previews themed-grid-col">
        <a href="/" class="text-decoration-none">
          <div>
            <div>
              <h5>
                <span>This is a Title</span>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 themed-grid-col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90"></div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 themed-grid-col">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect, I should have guessed there would be some special class for doing it "the Bootstrap way". Helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Just add class(text-decoration-none) to your link tag.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">Non-underlined link</a>
```

For more details:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/text

Answer (score 0):

I just added `text-decoration:none;` in your `<a>` tag as an inline-CSS and it worked like a charm.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Underline</title>
            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body class="py-0">

    <main>

        <div class="row mb-3 report-with-img-cont">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 report-previews themed-grid-col">
                
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h5>
                                <span>This is a Title</span>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 themed-grid-col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 themed-grid-col"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use bootstrap Property **`text-decoration-none`** in `<a>` tag

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Underline</title>
            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body class="py-0">

          <main>

              <div class="row mb-3 report-with-img-cont">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 report-previews themed-grid-col">

                      <a href="/" class="text-decoration-none">
                          <div>
                              <div>
                                  <h5>
                                      <span>This is a Title</span>
                                  </h5>
                              </div>
                              <div class="row d-flex">
                                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 themed-grid-col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90"></div>
                                  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 themed-grid-col"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a>

                  </div>
              </div>

          </main>

    </body>
    </html>
```